# Start learn SQL and need to know how it to do%

Tags: mysql, sql

What I do wrong? And can it be realised? I need show "summary of all revenue", "count of all revenue", "average revenue" and "average count of revenue per id" in range

```
SELECT `sum_revenue`, `allcnt_revenue`, `avg_revenue`, count(`cnt_revenue`) 
    FROM (SELECT sum(`revenue`) as sum_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION
    FROM (SELECT count(`revenue`) as allcnt_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION
    FROM (SELECT avg(`revenue`) as avg_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION   
    FROM (SELECT AVG(`revenue`) as cnt_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                GROUP BY `uid`) AS `Purchases`;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FROM (SELECT count(`revenue`) as allcnt_revenue             FROM
> `Purchases` WHERE `re' at line 8

In perfect world I want to see:

```
SELECT sum(`revenue`), 
count(`revenue`), 
avg(`revenue`), 
avg(count(`revenue`) by group `uid`) 
FROM `Purchases`
WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Comment: you're missing: `GROUP BY  \`sum_revenue\`, \`allcnt_revenue\`, \`avg_revenue\`` as to the whole query

Comment: Please share more details - is there anything not working with the given code? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: Nico, this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT count(`revenue`) as allcnt_revenue
   FROM `Purchases`
   WHERE `re' at line 7"

Comment: union from is not valid syntax , union select is

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are trying to do sample data and expected outcome would help clarify.

Comment: UPD the article, tried to explain my thoughts

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample data, the expected result corresponding to that data, and your approaches to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe  count(`cnt_revenue`)  won't work because you're missing to group by other fields then get the count:

```
SELECT `sum_revenue`, `allcnt_revenue`, `avg_revenue`, count(`cnt_revenue`) 
    FROM (SELECT sum(`revenue`) as sum_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION
    FROM (SELECT count(`revenue`) as allcnt_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION
    FROM (SELECT avg(`revenue`) as avg_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                ) AS `Purchases`
    UNION   
    FROM (SELECT AVG(`revenue`) as cnt_revenue
                FROM `Purchases`
                WHERE `revenue` BETWEEN 0 AND 10
                GROUP BY `uid`) AS `Purchases`
GROUP BY  `sum_revenue`, `allcnt_revenue`, `avg_revenue`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, then what you're trying to do is fetch data in two different levels of granularity in one go. That is not something SQL databases are designed for (unlike document or graph databases, which can return nested structures).

You can either separate your statement into two - one for the totals, one for the per uid count - or duplicate the totals into every row of the result, which might work with small data sets but unnecessarily fills the memory once you have many entries.

```sql
SELECT
 sum(`revenue`) as 'sum_revenue',
 count(`revenue`) as 'allcnt_revenue',
 avg(`revenue`) as 'avg_revenue'
FROM `Purchases`
;

SELECT uid, count(*) as 'purchases_per_uid'
FROM `Purchases`
GROUP BY `uid`
;
```

Afterwards, process the results in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you can do what you want with arithmetic.  If you want the average number of records per `uid`:

```
SELECT sum(revenue), count(revenue), avg(revenue),
       count(*) / count(distinct uid) 
FROM Purchases
WHERE revenue BETWEEN 0 AND 10;
```

If you want the average revenue per `uid`:

```
SELECT sum(revenue), count(revenue), avg(revenue),
       sum(revenue) / count(distinct uid) 
FROM Purchases
WHERE revenue BETWEEN 0 AND 10;
```